# Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services

i get this error on my angular 6 project when i try to fetch data from my api. This is my api json file;

```
{"data":
[{"category_name":"Women Ready Made","slug":null,"image_url":"education.jpg","products": 
[{"productName":"Kampala 
Shorts","description":"Beautiful Handwoven Kampala Shorts","imageUrl":"C:\\codes\\Tradsonline\\img\\image1.jpg","price":2500,"discount":10},{"productName":"Flowing White Agbada","description":"Flowing white agbada with beautiful design.","imageUrl":"C:\\codes\\Tradsonline\\img\\image3.jpg","price":22000,"discount":15}]},{"category_name":"Men's Ready Made","slug":null,"image_url":"education.jpg","products":[{"productName":"Ankara Jacket","description":"Ankara Jackets with pockets.","imageUrl":"C:\\codes\\Tradsonline\\img\\image2.jpg","price":5000,"discount":15},{"productName":"Women Ankara Gown","description":"Women Ankara gown with beautiful design.","imageUrl":"C:\\codes\\Tradsonline\\img\\image4.jpg","price":8000,"discount":0}]},{"category_name":"Ankara Gowns","slug":null,"image_url":"education.jpg","products":[]}]}
```

This is my service

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.base_url + 'categories')
    .pipe(map(res => {
       return res.data; //this is where the error happens
}));
```

this are my imports on my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Product } from '../models/product';
import { Category } from '../models/category';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Where does the error come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not specify a generic type parameter for `http.get` call then `object` is assumed so that is the type passed into `map`. `object` does not have a property named `data` (that you are calling) hence the transpile time error.

Change it so that you define the returned structure in the generic type constraint in the call to `http.get<T>`.

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get<{data: Category[]}>(this.base_url + 'categories')
        .pipe(map(res => {
          return res.data; // now .data is known and is expected to contain Category[]
        }));
}
```

Comment: Waow. Thank you a lot. You are a savior.